# Getting the Assigned ID of Button on Click

Tags: android

Lets say I have a XML layout with 20 ImageButtons.
Each ImageButton has been assigned an ID like:

```
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:id="@+id/button2"
..
upto
android:id="@+id/button20"
```

All the ImageButtons have been assigned to the same onClick Method in the layout XML using:

```
android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
```

In my Activity the Button click is handled using

```
public void onButtonClicked(final View v)
{

    Log.e("V", v.toString());
    Log.e("V",String.valueOf(v.getId()));

}
```

When a button is clicked, i want to get the value of my assigned id.
So if i click on button with my assigned id of say `android:id="@+id/button17"`
I want to say log the value `button17`

The above example logs the android assigned id like:

```
V: android.widget.ImageButton@415046c0
V: 2131492894
```

where as i want to get say `button17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());
```

is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The id you're getting is the `int` of the id as represented in `R.id`.

i.e. `v.getId() == R.id.button20`

You can translate it to a string, but I don't think you want to do that.